# Python Multithreading and Queues, thread will not be stopped

Tags: python, multithreading, visual-studio-code, queue

When the 'threadCounter' > 4, why the threads will not be stopped

What is the problem or how do I debug the root cause?

```
import threading, queue, time, os

def pop_nitems():
    for i in range(3):
        item = fifo_queue.get()
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Thread : {}. Retrieved & Processed Item : {}".format(threading.current_thread().name, item))
        fifo_queue.task_done()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fifo_queue = queue.Queue()
    threadCounter = 6

    for i in range(threadCounter):
        threading.Thread(target=pop_nitems, daemon=True, name="Thread-"+str(i+1)).start()

    for i in range(1, 13):
        fifo_queue.put("Task-{}".format(i))

    fifo_queue.join()

    print("\nAll items in queue completed. Exited from Main Thread\n")
    os.system('pause')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You start 6 threads. Each thread does a blocking get() on the queue 3 times. You put 12 items on the queue. Therefore your threads will block waiting on more queued items. Try range(18) instead of range(1,13)

Comment: @DarkKnight If I have 12 queue. How do I executing more than 4 threads at the time? for example no. of 8 threads

Comment: task_done() and join() (on the queue) are rarely necessary. My preference is to put something on the queue then create and start a new thread. Append the thread reference to a list. Once you've added everything you need to on the queue, iterate over the list calling join() (on the thread object reference) to ensure that all threads have completed before doing any more processing. This is a reasonable model for cases where the number of concurrent threads is likely to be low and you're not interested in return values from the threads. Otherwise, you should be looking at concurrent.futures